# load related enties without using include in Entity Framework Core

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am intended to load related entities without using include in C#/ Entity Framework.
In my example I have using left join to load all the questions options which only show if I explicitly say in select statement in LINQ query. My question how can I ensure it load related entities without defining related entity in select inside LINQ query .

### Data Model

```
public class QuestionDataModel : BasicDataModel
{
    public QuestionDataModel()
    {            
        QuestionOptions = new HashSet<QuestionOptionDataModel>();

    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<QuestionOptionDataModel> QuestionOptions { get; set; }

}
```

### LINQ Query

```
var q1 = (
           from question in Context.Questions
            join options in Context.QuestionOptions on question.Id equals options.QuestionId into qo
             where question.ConsultationId == Guid.Parse("10324003-0012-4D99-95D8-7E7189CA3888")
                select new
                  {
                    question
                    //,qo  // it only loads questionOption if qo is here, I need to do without that, since it is collection property in QuestionDataModel class
                  }
           ).ToList();
```

Comment: Do you want to load entities with or without include?

Comment: I want to load entities without include!

Comment: If you are using EF Core 2.1, You can enable lazy loading and related entities will be loaded when you explicitly call it. Refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#lazy-loading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the slower elements of a database conversation is the transfer of the selected data from the database management system to your process. It is wise not to send any more data to your process than you actually plan to use.

Apparently you have a sequence of `Questions` where every `Question` has zero or more `QuestionOptions`, and every `QuestionOption` belongs to exactly one `Question`, namely the `Question` with the `Id` equal to the `QuestionOption.QuestionId`. A simple one-to-many with a foreign key in `QuestionId`.

If you would fetch the `Question` with Id == 4 with its ten thousand `QuestionOptions`, you know that every `QuestionOption` will have a `QuestionId` that has a value of 4. You will be transferring the value 4 a 10 thousand times, while you'll probably wouldn't even use it, as you already know it equals the `Question.Id`.

> The solutions is: only use Include if you plan to update a database item.
>   In all other cases use Select.
>   Select only the properties you actually plan to use.

In Method syntax (or use a similar query syntax if you like)

```
var result = context.Questions.Join(context.QuestionOptions, // join Questions and QuestionOptions
    question => question.Id,                      // from every Question take the Id
    questionOption => questionOption.QuestionId,  // from every Option take the QuestionId
    (question, questionOption) => new              // when they match make a new object
    {    // Select only the properties you plan to use:
         Question = new 
         {
             Id = question.Id,
             ... other question properties
         },
         Option = new
         {
             Id = questionOption.Id,
             // not needed: questionOption.QuestionId, it equals Question.Id
             ... other properties you plan to use
         }
    });
```

Only do `ToList` if you really plan to use all fetched elements. Keep your result an IQueryable as long as possible.

If you rather have each `Question with its QuestionOptions`, consider using [Queryable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.groupby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var questionsWithTheirOptions = context.Questions
   .GroupJoin(context.QuestionOptions,            // GroupJoin Questions and QuestionOptions
    question => question.Id,                      // from every Question take the Id
    questionOption => questionOption.QuestionId,  // from every Option take the QuestionId
    (question, optionsOfQuestion) => new          // when they match make a new object
    {   // desired Question Properties
        Id = question.Id,
        ...

        // The options of this question:
        Options = optionsOfQuestion.Select(option => new
        {
            Id = questionOption.Id,
            // not needed: questionOption.QuestionId, it equals Question.Id
            ... 
        })
        .ToList()
    });
```

Comment: many thanks it help in my thinking and approach... one last thing... how group by can help to speed up ??

Comment: GroupBy? You mean GroupJoin? If one Question with 1000 options is queries in a normal join, how many times are the properties of the Question sent? And how many times would that be if you ask for one Question with its 1000 options using GroupJoin?